# File reading works on iOS Simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I made app that will be used in scientific data collection. It collects data through user interface, saves it as .csv and then that file is read and sent via email to predetermined collection email. It works perfectly in simulator, but when I test it on the device, the code simply returns null. 
I also have no idea how to check is the file saved on the device in the first place. I do realize that file might be not read simply because it is not there.

Here is the code that reads the file:

```
{
    NSLog(@"readFile");
    NSString *appFile = fileData;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appFile])
    {
        NSLog(@"found file");
        NSError *error= NULL;
        NSString *resultData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:appFile encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
        if (error == NULL)
            NSLog(@"No errors in reading");
            return resultData;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

together with call embedded in Button:

```
- (IBAction)sendData:(UIButton *)sender {
 // reading the data:

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *strHelp = [self readFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ObservationalData.csv"]];
 NSData *observationalData = [strHelp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];

 NSLog(@"Data: %@", strHelp); 
 ...
}
```

Following block of code is used to save the data:

```
- (IBAction)sendingData:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  NSError *error = nil;
  [_csvCollection writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ObservationalData.csv"]
      atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
  NSLog(@"Data Saved");
```

}

And this button also segues to the view controller where user can change the targeted email.

Anyway, when I run it on my device i get following error:

```
2015-08-21 15:53:07.814 DistenceBasedObservations[5701:1553004] readFile
2015-08-21 15:53:07.815 DistenceBasedObservations[5701:1553004] Data: (null)
2015-08-21 15:53:07.817 DistenceBasedObservations[5701:1553004] ***     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',   reason: '*** -[__NSCFString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x275b6137 0x35a2fc77 0x275b607d 0x2822ee23 0xa9481 0x2ac21a7b  0x2ac21a21 0x2ac0c5c5 0x2ac21461 0x2ac21133 0x2ac1aa41 0x2abf0c05  0x2ae6731f 0x2abef607 0x2757c22f 0x2757b643 0x27579cc1 0x274c59a1  0x274c57b3 0x2ec841a9 0x2ac50695 0xaedc9 0x35fd7aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: failed to send the k packet
```

Termination happens because I'm appending the string that should contain data to the body of the message. And of course, there is no string.

This is the example of the log output when I run the app on the simulator:

```
2015-08-21 16:44:54.512 DistenceBasedObservations[11827:276484] message >Body: Data are coming from:Left observer, start observing time is:(null), and set max distance: 200.  

2015-08-21 16:44:58.937 DistenceBasedObservations[11827:276484] readFile
2015-08-21 16:44:58.982 DistenceBasedObservations[11827:276484] found file
2015-08-21 16:44:59.002 DistenceBasedObservations[11827:276484] No errors in reading
2015-08-21 16:44:59.002 DistenceBasedObservations[11827:276484] Data: time,observer,lat,long,doe,fawn,buck,distance
2015-08-07 23:51:02 +0000,Right,37.48859,-122.2984,3,1,1,183
2015-08-19 21:11:40 +0000,Front,37.33428,-122.0787,3,3,1,243
2015-08-19 21:12:01 +0000,Front,37.33862,-122.0855,3,1,1,214
2015-08-21 16:45:09.020 DistenceBasedObservations[11827:276484] Mail sent
```

And this is the reason why I think that file might not be saved in the first place on the device. Variable _csvCollection is formed correctly, log output confirms that, but I do not know how to check is the file in the device. Nor why it does not save the file (if the file is not saved). There are 18 gigs available on device so space should not be an issue.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: On a device, have you verified that `sendingData:` is successfully writing the file? You don't check the return value of `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`. If it returns `NO`, log `error`.

Comment: Check return value and handle errors, don't crash!

Comment: You are better off using `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` and using the error parameter to get the reason of the failure.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. 
Suggestion that I should check an output of error variable worked. I found the mistake and now it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks once more for comments rmaddy and zaph!

You showed me the correct path.

I made mistake by placing the code for saving the data into the

```
-(IBAction)...
```

, when I moved it to

```
-(void)prepareForSegue...
```

it worked as charm. So that is the fix.

Thanks again on the comments.